# Facebook debugger sees images on my site, but when I post it shows up blank

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I enter any of my pages at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
I am able to see the images on my page. If I post a link to my page on my newsfeed, the preview shows all the correct info with the image showing correctly as well.

Once I post to my news feed, using either the share button on my site or by actually posting the link directly on my news feed, the correct text information shows up, but the images are blank.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I've debugged/had facebook scrape my pages several times.

I do get a warning when I debug the website:

> fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so
>   that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the
>   app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share
>   dialog. Otherwise, the default app id( ########### ) will be assigned.

But I didn't think that should cause this issue? I have already made an update to add the app_id, but that is in process and not live yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Faceebook Lint is having some issues at the moment. We tried it yesterday at worked, today the exact same post is showing a blank image in Lint. What you can do is place a "?" after the image to force a refresh from the cache.
Example: **www.somedomain.com/image.jpg?234234234** then try and re-fetch from Facebook Lint. We had the same problem and currently images are showing a blank image.
If not try again in 24 hours if the issue has been resolved.